# Dynamic hedge ratio in R

Tags: r, loops

I was trying to convert the Chan code about Pairs Trading strategy with dynamic hedge ratio into R.
I have already done all work with a steady hedge, but if I want to replicate his "for" loop I'm in trouble. Here my code for that part

```
    lookback=20
hedge=rep(NaN,length(stockY))
for (i in lookback:length(hedge)){
  reg=lm(stockY[i-lookback +1:i]~stockX[i-lookback +1:i])
  hedge[i]=reg[1]$coeff[2]
  }
```

I tried many different attempts but my low level in R is pretty evident here. I'm not trying to use a "lapply" function but just a for loop. Hope someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: Please add a link to the Chan code you are talking about, not everybody is familiar with it.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's a book, I don't know where to find a link. Anyway I'll explain what I wrote and what I need: I'm doing a "for loop" regression (lm) between stockY and stockX. This regression must be done for every 20 observations (=lookback).I'm doing it for the length of stockY (which is the length I set for the hedge ratio too). Every lm (so for every 20 observations at time) gives me a hedge (slope of regression). I want to have as output a vector with all hedge found. But I failed every attempts I did

Answer (score 0):

Ok It seems I did it. The following is my code:

```
 lookback=20
hedge=data.frame(hedge=rep(0,length(stockY)))

for (i in lookback:length(stockY)){
  reg=summary(lm(stockY[i-lookback +1:i]~stockX[i-lookback +1:i]))
  hedge[i,1]=reg$coefficients[2,1]
  }
```

So, now I'd know how to extract my residuals. I mean, I need to list all residuals from regression. Unfortunately if I write reg$residuals it returns my last 20 residuals from the last iteration of the loop. So, I tried to include another "res" vector like "hedge" but.....I can't extract my residuals. Please, can someone help me?